# How i can update the value for any key by adding on the current value

Tags: mysql

I have a table X where there are values for approver_grp as 210061280,200019820 for one row , 213044040 for another and so on ..
I wish to add 212031856 and 21202589 to the existing values.
Can you please suggest what sql statement can be used to update these values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: update table_name set column_name=concat(column_name,',','212031856,21202589') where id= specific_row_id

Comment: update tbl_name set column_name=concat(column_name,',','212031856,21202589') where id= specific_row_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CONCAT()`  and if you want update specific row only means use where condition otherwise leave it .

```
update table_name set column_name=concat(column_name,',','212031856,21202589') where id= specific_row_id
```